# Positioning a headline with a text below, plus background-color issue

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a headline and a text below it. The idea of the styling is the following:

- the headline and the text below are aligned to the left
- the headline has a background color set, with a fill only from the
  left side of the screen
- both texts are in a horizontally-centered wrapper

Like this:

[image]

Independently of the screen size, the headline's background color always starts at the left screen edge.

I have no idea how to keep both texts aligned to the left and style the background of the headline. Even with absolute positioning, this seems hacky.

Any good ideas?

Basic Fiddle **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/jce541hr/4/)**.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Fancy headline<br> of doom</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
</div>


body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  background-color: #3f72a7;
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a pseudo element to create the overflowing part:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  background-color: #3f72a7;
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

h1:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 100%;
  left: -10000px;
  background-color: #3f72a7;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Fancy headline<br> of doom</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice! I was considering a pseudo element but wasn't sure how to make it as high as the text. `top: 0; bottom: 0;` is the answer to that. Thank you.